# What is the proper way to share derived data between functions, defined inside functional component in react

Tags: reactjs

What is the proper way to share `computedData` between `getSomeMessage` and `getAnotherMessage`

```
import React from "react";

const SOME_CONST = 10;

function Component(props) {
  const getSomeMessage = () => {
    const { prop } = props;

    const computedData = prop * SOME_CONST;

    return `Some message ${computedData}`;
  };

  const getAnotherMessage = () => {
    const { prop } = props;

    const computedData = prop * SOME_CONST;

    return `Another message ${computedData}`;
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {getSomeMessage()}
      {getAnotherMessage()}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Pass as a parameter since they are just functions. `props` and `prop` are both in functional component scope, while `SOME_CONST` is in file scope. And please don't use `Component` as component name, it'll conflict with any class-based component extending react's Component.

Comment: @DrewReese but where I should do computing `prop * SOME_CONST` inside each function?

Comment: It's the same `prop` and `SOME_CONST` in both cases, so using the DRY principle you loft it to the common "parent". This is the react pattern for passing common state/data/whatever to children/ancestors.

Comment: @DrewReese got it. But if `SOME_CONST` only makes sense in the module where the Component is defined

Comment: This is the scenario you've painted with your question and code snippet. Do you have a different use-case? If so, then please update question for *that* scenario. BTW, the answer will probably still be the same. [Lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

Comment: I want to get general solutions. But I understand you. Raise the calculation higher level. This is good advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can put it in the beginning of component function like this

```
import React from "react";

const SOME_CONST = 10;

function Component(props) {
   const computedData = props.prop * SOME_CONST;

   const getSomeMessage = () => `Some message ${computedData}`;

   const getAnotherMessage = () => `Another message ${computedData}`;

   return (
      <div>
        {getSomeMessage()}
        {getAnotherMessage()}
      </div>
   );
 }
```

Comment: Thank you But what if I pass a lot of properties to the component, and it’s not convenient to destruct them so I want to have props inside the component scope

Comment: I've edited the answer, so you may use it with many props, and in convenient way

Comment: What is your opinion on this approach `const computedData = getComputedData()` and define `getComputedData` inside Component?

Comment: if there is need for calculate computedData every time you call a function, it is a good option, but I thinks it's better to store it in component function as a simple number. In case from the snippet you printed second option is way better for performance